# Loading image from parent frame to child

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have an upload button on my main page that submits to a php form, then returns the image back to the main page. What I am trying to do now is get the image element to load to an Iframe in the parent page as a variable that I can put in a div. Everything is functioning properly until the image will not display in the part of the Iframe, I think I am close but cannot see what is wrong in my code.

index.html 
 just the javascript , iframe, and id where the messages appears

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updatepicture(pic) {
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", pic);
    $("#iFrameThingy").contents().find("#message").attr("src","photos/cw/briantest/" +pic);
}
</script>
<iframe id="iFrameThingy" src="Templates/template2/index.html" width="100%" height="4500" name="search_iframe"></iframe>
<p id="message">Upload message will go here.</p>
```

iframe.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function updatepicture(pic){
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",pic);
}
</script>
--> Where I am trying to place the image
        <div class="caption2">
        <img id="productImage"  id="images/product.png"alt="Product" height="416" width="417"> 
    </div>
```

I had this working at one point but mistakenly changed something and now it is not working but I know I am close. Any help is appriciated

upload.php

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 0) {

if ($_FILES['file']['size'] <= 153600) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "images/".$_FILES['file']["name"])) {
        // file uploaded

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        parent.document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
        parent.document.getElementById("file").value = "";
        window.parent.updatepicture("<?php echo 'images/'.$_FILES['file']["name"]; ?>");
        </script>
        <?php

    } else {
        // the upload failed

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        parent.document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<font color='#ff0000'>There was an error uploading your image. Please try again later.</font>";
        </script>           
        <?php

    }
} else {
    // the file is too big

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    parent.document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<font color='#ff0000'>Your file is larger than 150kb. Please choose a different picture.</font>";
    </script>
    <?php

    }

}

?>
```

index.html (submit form)

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="iframe">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

Upload message will go here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",pic);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("productImage").setAttribute("src",pic);
```

And change this:

```
<img id="productImage"  id="images/product.png"alt="Product" height="416" width="417">
```

to this:

```
<img id="productImage"  alt="Product" height="416" width="417">
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I made the changes but now the upload image button displays "No file chosen", yet it is uploading to the folder correctly. I added my upload.php file and the form i use to submit

Comment: What do you mean it says that? Before or after you press to browse for a file? After submitting?

Comment: Yes beside the "choose file" button, i select the image, click upload. It then upload and displays the image in the parent frame, but says "No file chosen"

Comment: Just solved it, I have been going over this for a while and just missed a typo. Your solution worked as well, Thanks.

Comment: 90% of the time when something's not working, it's because I made a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect id there:

```
$("#iFrameThingy").contents().find("#message").attr("src","photos/cw/briantest/" +pic);
```

You should use *productImage* instead of *message*. Use this:

```
$("#iFrameThingy").contents().find("#productImage").attr("src","photos/cw/briantest/" +pic);
```

Comment: Yes this fixed it, same as Don suggested